# python/ pandas data frame row manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python/ pandas and wondering if there is anyway to get the expected below output from a single data frame.

Example data:

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | CA_1,CA_2 | 10 |
| AAB | CA_1,CA_3 | 20 |
| AAC | CA_2,CA_3 | 30 |

[image]

raw data
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (df
   .assign(**{'column 2': df['column 2'].str.split(',')})
   .explode('column 2')
   .groupby('column 2', as_index=False)
   .agg({'column 1': ','.join, 'column 3': 'sum'})
)
```

Output:

```
  column 2 column 1  column 3
0     CA_1  AAA,AAB        30
1     CA_2  AAA,AAC        40
2     CA_3  AAB,AAC        50
```

Comment: thanks for this though I get TypeError: sequence item 1046: expected str instance, float found, I attached on the working data above

Comment: Then you likely have NaNs, can you try to replace `','.join` by `lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna())` (or `lambda x: ','.join(x.fillna('NA'))`)

Comment: @DEB good news, you might want to update the example in your question for future readers ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
(df.assign(**{'column 2': df['column 2'].str.split(',')})
   .explode('column 2')
   .assign(**{'column 3': lambda x: x.groupby('column 2')['column 3'].transform('sum'), 
              'column 1': lambda x: x.groupby('column 2')['column 1'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))})
   .drop_duplicates()
   .rename(columns={'column 1': 'column1', 'column 2': 'column2', 'column 3': 'column3'})
)
```